# Managing windows when local SAS session starts

Tags: session, sas, window, startup

When a SAS session starts, there are 5 windows. (Result Viewer, Explorer, Log, Editor, Output).

**My desired state is when the session starts:**

- No result viewer
- No output window
- No default explorer window
- The useable explorer window default open(to clarify this i attached a picture)
  [Good/Bad explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvT5d.gif)
- Enchanced editor open
- Log window open

So there will be 3 windows opened at session start, and i would like to resize them into 3 columns.

**What i got so far:**

1. I know the task can be done, because i was able to do this on my working computer. Unfortunately they reinstalled my windows without a word, and i lost my setup. And i did not have my autoexec/sasv9cfg file backuped. :(
2. I can close the output window with **dm listing off** command in my autoexec.
3. I can resize the 3 windows if i have them, with **dm wdef** command as well.

My biggest issue is i cant find again a DM/ODS or any kind of command, which closes the Result Viewer, and the original Explorer, and opens the normal/usable Explorer. In my faded memories i needed only 1 DM/ODS/sth command to achieve these 3 steps at once. Of course,  if we can find a solution in more steps, thats also completely fine.

Big thx for any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want the `DMSEXP` docked windows (which includes ODS Results tab) at session start up.  The only way to do this programmatically is to specify the SAS system option `-nodmsexp` in the `sas.exe` command line or `config.sys`.

So, on my system, I set the target command on my SAS icon to be:

```
"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"
  -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg"
  -NODMSEXP
```

Tweak the SAS DM session window states by placing this code in your `autoexec.sas`

```
dm 'dmsexp;tree on;next;listing off;tile vert' ;
```

You can also fiddle around with your session start up using the system options:

- `initstmt=`
- `initcmd`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The DMSEXP option was the keyword i could not remember.